# how to read HTML paragraph and combine with the text with a string value?

Tags: html, asp.net, string

I have a string something like "This items belongs to company1 "

I have a HTML page with a paragraph "This is fixed section."

I want to to read the HTML page paragraph and combine the text with my string.

How is this possible someone please help me......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/HTMLPage.htm")); 
string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on how you want to combine it

1- if you want this string to be in the beginning of your HTML then you can easily use the following:

```
string data=html.Replace("<p>",stringValue);
```

2- if you want to combine it at the end of the html then use the following

```
string data=html.Replace("</p>",stringValue);
```

and if you want to keep the html alone and the string value alone then

```
string data= html + stringValue
```

hope that it will help you
regards

Comment: I have a HTML page from that how will I get the paragraph, can u please tell me

Comment: you can use regular expression to get the paragraph

Comment: here an example for how to use regular expression to read paragraph from html file http://www.dotnetperls.com/paragraph-html